# Second argument when emitting messages with process.send

Tags: node.js, ipc

*main.js*

```
let child = require('child_process').fork('./child.js');

child.on('message', function () {
    console.log('message', arguments)
});
```

*child.js*

```
process.send({ ... });
```

It appears that the handler is called with two arguments:

> { '0': { ... }, '1': undefined }

I'm counting on arguments length in `message` listener, so the exact number of arguments is important.

What is the second argument (`undefined`)? Is it there unconditionally in all Node.js versions?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_message

Comment: @robertklep - That's an answer - you should post it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [fine manual](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_event_message) states:

> **Event: 'message'**
>
> • `message` `<Object>` a parsed JSON object or primitive value.
>
> • `sendHandle` `<Handle>` a `net.Socket` or `net.Server` object, or undefined.

If you search for *sendHandle* on the same page, you end up [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback), specifically:

> The optional `sendHandle` argument that may be passed to `child.send()` is for passing a TCP server or socket object to the child process. The child will receive the object as the second argument passed to the callback function registered on the `process.on('message')` event.

However, in your situation you're sending the message in the other direction, from child to server, in which case sending a handle doesn't make sense. Hence, my guess would be that the second argument will *always* be `undefined` in that case (but will still be present).